# SharePoint Hosted App Error "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am developing a SharePoint Hosted App on office 365 using REST API's and Anjular js. I am able to read the host list and when I try and update it give me this Error "the given key was not present in the dictionary". Can't figure out what needs to be done.
This is the code that actually performance the operation

```
$http(
        {
            method: "POST",
            url: empMstDetails[0].__metadata.uri, // getSiteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(‘Employee Master')/items(" + empMstDetails[0].Employee_x0020_ID + ")",
            body: {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.Employee_x0020_MasterListItem' }, 'Title': 'TestUpdated'
            },
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "IF-MATCH": "*",
                "X-HTTP-Method":"MERGE",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                "content-length":0
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where in this code are you accessing a dictionary?

Comment: I am just updating a single field in the host web list. I don't have any dictionary specified.

Comment: I think we are going to need more code than this.

Comment: It not allowing me to pas the code.. in a nut shell I have a factory function defined in angular and this is the code that does the post

Comment: this is a sharepoint hosted app and I am not using any dictionary object. Don't know if sharepoint does something after the rest call

Comment: Why are you setting content-length to 0?

Answer (score 1):

You should use 'data' instead of 'body'. That should clear out this error message, which is kind of confusing. -sean

Comment: what is the value of request digest. Im already authenticating with oath token. Do i still need it?